# Trying to combine php and chart.js json into same .php file using custom mysql queries

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, json, dynamic

I have an html form which passes user selected categories to a php file which then queries a mysql database and sends the data back in a table format. I was hoping to evolve the php script to then give the user an option to see a line chart rather than a simple table (or perhaps both). After some extensive research, it seems there are options to cause the php script to stylize the output into a json format. From there I can use charts.js or ??. However - the data from mysql is not static, it's being selectively posted dynamically based on user input. This is where I'm getting a little lost in pulling it all together.
Here is the HTML:

```
<html><head></head><body>
<form name="form" method="POST" action="php/processor.php">
<p>Start Date <input type="text" name="from_date" id="from_date" value="2016-04-07"></p>
<p>Start Time <input id="from_time" type="text" name="from_time" value="00:00" /></p>
<p>End Time <input id="to_time" type="text" name="to_time" value="23:59" /></p>
<input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value="Value1" id="Value1">Value1
<input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value="Value2" id="Value2">Value2
<!-- etc. (Value 3, Value 4, .....)-->
<input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="submit" >
<input type="reset" name="reset" value="reset">
</form>
</body></html>
```

Here is the PHP Script I am trying to use (processor.php):

```
<html><head>
<script src="assets/Chart.js-2.1.6/src/Chart.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head><body>
<?php
    $servername = "domain.com";
    $username = "username";
    $password = "password";
    $dbname="database";
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
if($_POST['submit'] == "submit")
{
$from_date = ($_POST['from_date']);
$to_date = ($_POST['from_date']);
$from_time = ($_POST['from_time']);
$to_time = ($_POST['to_time']);
}
//form processing
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
$checklist     = $_POST['check_list'];
$allowedFields = [
    'Value1'     => 'Value1',
    'Value2' => 'Value2',
// etc, Value3, Value 4 ....
];
$wantedFields   = [];
$tableDynFields = [];
foreach ($checklist as $field) {
    if (array_key_exists($field, $allowedFields)) {
        $wantedFields[]   = $field;
        $tableDynFields[] = $allowedFields[$field];
    }
}
if ($wantedFields) {
    $wantedFields = join(',', $wantedFields) . ',';
} else {
    $wantedFields = '';
}
$sql = "SELECT Fdate, {$wantedFields} Ftime FROM hourly_db WHERE Fdate BETWEEN '$from_date' AND '$to_date' AND Ftime BETWEEN '$from_time' AND '$to_time' LIMIT 600";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
}
if ($result->num_rows >0) {
    echo "<table><tr><th>Date</th><th>Time</th>";                                                    
        foreach($tableDynFields as $c) {                                       
            echo "<th>$c</th>";
        }
        echo "</tr>";
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {                         
            echo "<tr><td>".$row["Fdate"]."</td><td>".$row["Ftime"]."</td>";                                        
            foreach($tableDynFields as $c) {                                   
                echo "<td>".$row[$c]."</td>";
            }
            echo "</tr>";
        }                                                               
        echo "</table>"; 
  $result->free(); 
    } else {
        echo "query failed.<hr/>";
    }
$conn->close();
?>
<canvas id="myLineChart" width="740" height="200"></canvas>
<script>
  function drawLineChart() {
    // Add a helper to format timestamp data
    Date.prototype.formatMMDDYYYY = function() {
        return (this.getMonth() + 1) +
        "/" +  this.getDate() +
        "/" +  this.getFullYear();
    }
    var jsonData = $.ajax({
      data: <?php echo json_encode($row);?>,
      dataType: 'json',
    }).done(function (results) {
      // Split timestamp and data into separate arrays
      var labels = [], data=[];
      results["packets"].forEach(function(packet) {
        labels.push(new Date(packet.timestamp).formatMMDDYYYY());
        data.push(parseFloat(packet.payloadString));
      });
      // Create the chart.js data structure using 'labels' and 'data'
      var tempData = {
        labels : labels,
        datasets : [{
            fillColor             : "rgba(151,187,205,0.2)",
            strokeColor           : "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
            pointColor            : "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
            pointStrokeColor      : "#fff",
            pointHighlightFill    : "#fff",
            pointHighlightStroke  : "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
            data                  : data
        }]
      };
      var ctx = document.getElementById("myLineChart").getContext("2d");
      var myLineChart = new Chart(ctx).Line(tempData, {
        //bezierCurve: false
      });
    });
  }
  drawLineChart();
</script>
</body></html>
```

In the above example, I've tried using the chart.js example I found for creating a line chart, trying to get the Date on the Y axis and the data on the X axis for a single category of data (eventually, I will want the user to be able to add up to 4 variables in the line chart with the date (or time depending on the intervals) on the X axis and the variables plotted on the Y axis, including a secondary Y axis when I eventually find the functionality). However, right now, the output shows my table exactly as it is supposed to be, but does not show any chart at all (not that need to show them both, but I've kept the table data on there just to make sure the php script continues to work without any other errors). I was hoping that instead of a URL pointing to the processor.php in a separate html file that I could use data and create the php json reference together (data: ). I've tried this with the line graph javascript in the header as well with no change. Is $row not the correct reference or do I need to add another reference in the php under $results like $data = $row[] and use $data? Am I missing something in trying to combine the javascript and php together in a .php file? If json needs to be called as a url from a separate html (such as processor.html for example), then how would I best pass the form data from the original HTML into both processor.php and processor.html? I cannot find an instance of this online (combining the javascript & php for line graphs with dynamic field input). I am open to any other version of graphing code, although I would eventually like to transform this into a more friendly user control panel type interface and most likely cannot use google graphs due to the sensitive nature of the data. I thought that due to the way the form is being handled, maybe the php file would have to write a .json file on the server and then a separate html file would use the url reference directly to the .json file (just overwriting it each time?), but I am still not sure how to change the form to send the data to both files and then I'm not sure if 1) the html file would process faster than the written .json file and 2) what the correct format would be in javascript to directly reference the json file?

Comment: Note, you dont need `$.ajax({` if you are print the result on the page, so just do `var  data=<?php echo json_encode($row);?>;`

Comment: Another Note, use `F12` in your webbrowser for open the debug console (maybe another key on any browser) and look for errors, i thing your code is not working currently